# error while sending transaction with solanaweb3, [ReferenceError: Property 'Buffer' doesn't exist] in react native

Tags: sendtransactionerror, buffer

the part of code that causes
const connection = new Connection('https://api.testnet.solana.com');
console.log(privateKey, '+++++++++');

```
  const feePayer = Keypair.fromSecretKey(bs58.decode(privateKey));
  console.log('feepair', feePayer);
  const transaction = new web3.Transaction().add(
    web3.SystemProgram.transfer({
      fromPubkey: feePayer.publicKey,
      toPubkey: data.to,
      lamports: web3.LAMPORTS_PER_SOL / 100,
    }),
  );
```

Comment: I am Having the same error while download the video from Url. Thanks it works for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because react-native doesn't have `window.Buffer` defined by default, which the web3.js library is trying to use.

You can fix it by adding to the top of your app:

```
global.Buffer = require('buffer').Buffer;
```

Comment: thanks @Callum M ,made my day

Comment: I was using another web3 lib, and encountered the same issue, your solution saved my day as well. Thank you